# password confirmation with sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to set up password confirmation in sails 0.10.0-rc9. this is for a new user sign-up. when i use the same password in both fields, console confirms it's grabbing the same passwords, then spits out the error that they don't match. I want to know what I'm missing...

the model - user.js - looks like 
https://github.com/mrcn/C_Express/blob/master/api/models/User.error.js

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: "string",
      email: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    encryptedPassword: {
      type: "string"
    },
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      delete obj.confirmation;
      delete obj.encryptedPassword;
      delete obj._csrf;
      return obj;
    }
  },
  beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
      console.log("Called beforeCreate User ");
      console.log(values);
    if(!values.password || values.password != values.confirmation) {
      console.log("\n if statement call \n");
      return next({
        err : ["password dont match."]
      });
    }
  }
};
```

the form looks like this: 
https://github.com/mrcn/C_Express/blob/master/views/user/new.ejs

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="your name" name="name" required />

  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email address" name="email" data-parsley-trigger="change" required />

  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password" required />

  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="confirmation" name="confirmation" required />
  <br />

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Create Account" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<% _csrf %>" />
```

when i use random "wer" for everything, Console logs"

```
Called beforeCreate User
{ name: 'wer',
  email: 'wer@wer.com',
  password: 'wer',
  confirmation: 'wer',
  _csrf: '',
  id: null }

 if statement call

{ err: [ 'password dont match.' ] }
```

Comment: Can you show the log you're seeing?  Also, you'll need to call `next()` in the success case as well, or your model will never get created...

Comment: i updated the post with the console log.

i sort of gutted all the other stuff from the model to figure out this problem first.

Comment: Erm, something is amiss.  Are you sure the code you're posting is what you actually have in your app?  It works fine for me.

Comment: when i fixed the typo error i saved it to a different file. stackoverflow, please forgive me for this

Comment: It happens.  You can always remove your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe spell `password` the same in both places? :P

```
if(!values.password || values.pasword != values.confirmation) {
                                ^oops
```

Answer (score 0):

**beforeCreate** changes to **beforeValidate** Ç